# Is it allowed to use Model property in Django south migration, and why?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm using south to do schema and data migration in Django. I have a model like this:

```
class ModelFoo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

And in south data migration code, I want to use full_name directly, like this:

```
foo.full_name
```

But I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'ModelFoo' object has no attribute 'full_name'
```

What's going wrong here? I sure it's OK to use 'full_name' in the view code of Django, why it fails here?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314173/how-to-call-a-static-methods-on-a-django-model-class-during-a-south-migration?rq=1

Comment: thx, It sounds like a good reason, but some times it's really a lot of pain for not allowed to use it. Maybe there should be some settings that can change be behavior, and the developer is responsible for keep method there in later versions of the code, if he/she turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jayesh's link explains, you should not do this, because the methods could disappear later from your code, and it would break your migration.

However, you could be pretty sure that you will run this migration once, and never come back, or if for any other reason you want to risk this and reuse your property, maybe because it is ugly heavy, then you would accomplish it by importing your real model in migration and using that property, like this:

```
from models import ModelFoo
ModelFoo.full_name.fget(foo)
```

where `foo` is the variable from your example (the instance of south migration model class).

That is how you call a property from another class, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021464/how-to-call-a-property-of-the-base-class-if-this-property-is-being-overwritten-i).