# django 1.8 - object has no attribute error on migration's RunPython

Tags: django

I am trying to add a new field to one of my models and I want to populate this field for all the existing instances of that module using the migration's RunPython.

The problem is that populationg is being done using a class method of another model which has a ForeignKey to this model:

```
class A(mptt_models.MPTTModel):
    baz = models.ForeignKey(to='b.B', related_name='aaa', ...)

    def get_yun(self):
        return "YUN"

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'b'

class B(models.Model):
    foo = ...
    yun = models.CharField(...) # This is the new field

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'b'
```

My migration file contain this function which invoked using `migrations.RunPython` after `migration.AddField` operation:

```
def set_yun(apps, schema_editor):
    B = apps.get_model("b", "B")

    for b in B.objects.all()
        b.yun = b.aaa.first().get_yun()
```

The last line throws `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'get_yun'`

I read similar question and I understood that `apps.get_model` returns a shallow model which doesn't contain the methods I declared in the model class.

However none of the answers worked for me (it looks like they are relevant to newer versions of django - I am using `1.8`)

Is there a way to populate my new field using RunPython through the migration file or I would have to do it manualy after modifing the models?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `for b in B.objects.all()` instead of `for b i B.objects.all()`?

Comment: Indeed. Typo, thanks

Comment: You've obfuscated your code too much. Even on the real models, `a.get_yun()` would cause an error because `yun` is a field on B, not A, and `get_root()` would return the root instance of A. Should it be `self.get_root().baz.yun`? It's probably more helpful to post your real code as much as possible.

Comment: How is the result from that `get_yun()` operation generated? Is that retrieved or calculated from another table in the database? If so, it's possible to use `B.objects.update(yun=F([some expression]))` or something like that to update the B table in a single query.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I honestly not sure how it works but it is. I traveld the models but couldn't find where the connection is made (but believe me it is there somewhere :D). Fortunatlly it doesn't matter to the core of my question. let's assume that `get_yun` returns some constant (see update) - the error is still raised. Regarding the the real code, it is much more "spaghettish" so I had to minimize it somehow, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: But now you've obfuscated it even further, which isn't helpful. The point is that you will need to replicate the logic of whatever that is doing, you can't access the actual method. If it is calling the MPTT `get_root` method, you will need to translate that into the underlying db filter calls.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but as far as I see it the main issue is that model methods are not accessible when fetching the modle using `apps.get_model` the rest might be indeed completely noise.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I managed to gain access by import the real model like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102931/how-to-access-models-class-level-variable-in-data-migration. From your experience is that a no-no path to go through? or is it good enough if I only populate a field? Thanks .